# How to give value to dynamic inputbox using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, user-input

I need to pass a value to dynamic inputbox which has dynamic id.My code is:

```
<table id="combobox-1281-triggerWrap" class="x-form-trigger-wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody><tr>
<td id="combobox-1281-inputCell" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;">
<input id="combobox-1281-inputEl" type="text" role="combobox" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" autocomplete="off" name="combobox-1281-inputEl" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="x-hide-display x-form-data-hidden" role="presentation" id="ext-gen1728"></div></td>
<td role="presentation" id="combobox-1281-sideErrorCell" width="22" style="display: none;">
<div role="presentation" id="combobox-1281-errorEl" class="x-form-invalid-icon x-form-invalid-icon-focus" style="display:none">
</div></td>
<td role="presentation" valign="top" class=" x-trigger-cell x-unselectable" style="width:28px;" id="ext-gen1727">
<div class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-first rp-icon-expanded" role="presentation" id="ext-gen1726"></div>
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Here "combobox-1281-inputEl" =>1281 is dynamically creating and the class name also not unique, how to give the value to this inputbox.

Comment: Share please complete HTML with the label

Comment: If there's no unique locator, you can use labels(if exist) from the page as reference. Updated HTML not include label text of the input, like "Username" or "Country"..., visible for user. You can also add screenshot also of the page, if you don't understand what is label. Or share the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for partial `id` attribute that starts with `combobox-` and ends with `-inputEl`. You can get there from the parent`<td>`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id^="combobox-"][id$="-inputCell"] > [id^="combobox-"][id$="-inputEl"]')
```

You can also extract the dynamic part and use it to locate other elements

```
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id^="combobox-"][id$="-inputCell"]')
number = table.get_attribute('id').split('-')[1]
driver.find_element_by_id(f'combobox-{number}-inputEl')
```

Comment: There are many comboboxlike this,and only the number is changing

Comment: @DivyaMani Are there also many `<table>`s with `id="combobox-1281-triggerWrap"`?

Comment: Yes.many tables with id which starts with combobox- and ends with -inputEl,but the inbetween id is dynamic

Comment: @DivyaMani What about ancestors or siblings element with unique text or attributes? what is your criteria of clicking that item if you do it manually?

Comment: td : combobox- -inputCell is unique.how to traverse td to div to inputbox

Comment: Can you explain what split('-')[1] this means

Comment: @DivyaMani `split('-')` will create a list of three strings, `['combobox', '1281', 'inputCell']`. `[1]` take the element in index 1, the `1281`.